# Display Items from a list as column depending on class only with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Im trying to display the items of a list depending on their class as two seperated columns  without adding extra html wrappers or using Jquery.

I've postet an example here http://codepen.io/danielschmid/pen/vwcta/?editors=010 **Note:** I’ve only added the margin-left and right to better exemplifie what im trying to achive.

The only way i can think of it would be with absolute positions but than i need to know the size of any element and add an individual top position as an offset like here: http://codepen.io/danielschmid/pen/aKBrc/

Any ideas ?

thanks,

daniel

Comment: Please post the code from CodePen in your question directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to `float` only one of them, the other needs its layout triggered with `overflow:hidden;`.

No `margin` should be used.

to keep the  non floatting `li` standing on `right` side, you can reset **`direction`** on `ul` and set it back on `li`.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Imote)**

---

to go further to avoid gaps, you will unfortunately need to multiplicate selectors to test if so many of one kind stands ahead to apply the right negative margin-top. **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/GhkiD/)** . this can be endless if `ul` has hundreds of `li`s :)

Comment: this works if first li has to float left, else , swap float to right onto other class and forget about direction. there will still be some gaps appearing if there is more non floatting li than floatting , when a floatting li comes in the flow. float always break a line before floatting.

Comment: I've tried to implement that technique in my layout and encountered some problems. As you see here it doesnt always work that way. Depends on the distribution of the list elements: http://codepen.io/danielschmid/pen/lepLk

Comment: @DanielSchmid as i said , some gaps will still remain. you can try to multiplicate selectors (sass routine would do it) , but not too sure it is a godd idea, thinking of ressources used by browser to test each selector. for i.e. : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/EirFC , it would be like : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/GhkiD/

Comment: ok sorry didnt get that before but thats what i thought. Same problem with absolute positions...

Comment: absolute position is not really a good idea either , it easily breaks, what's left would be some javascript. but this is beyond my possibilities , i'm not a programmer.

Comment: @DanielSchmid the easiest way , would be to sort them on server side before to send them as HTML to the browser.

Comment: That snippet is part of a static-site build with jekyll. What i'm going to do is to create an "dynamic" stylsheet with a particular margin for every post. that should work fine.